# How can I use the YQL Finance API to retrieve a list of all IPOs in a given time frame?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I've tried reviewing the YQL documentation, but can't figure out how to use dates to limit my queries. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an answer specifically to your problem, but it might give you an idea how to solve your problem:

The following is my approach to query the yahoo.finance.historicaldata table within a specific time frame (startDate, endDate):

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20=%20%22AAPL%22%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222015-01-1%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222015-01-2%22&format=xml&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

[Execute query](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20=%20%22AAPL%22%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222015-01-1%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222015-01-2%22&format=xml&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)